# Responding to a coordinated attack against financial transaction systems

Tags: attacks, incident-response, trust, financial

Imagine a coordinated attack by a large and motivated hacking group, that results in a nation-level compromise of the financial systems we take for granted: credit card payments, accounts at the top banks, the ACH system etc.

What remediation strategies could be employed after the public outcry, as individuals become financially frozen, illicit transactions remain uncorrected, and trust in financial transactions drops to zero, to prevent (or at least recover from) total chaos?

Comment: I know it sounds almost flippant, but this might get useful answers on Worldbuilding.se - they specialise in this kind of thought process.

Comment: Closed here, however the OP has asked the question in a better way at http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/36361/188

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the scenarios countries practice, with joined up activity between government, financial services, telcos, utilities etc.

These simulations happen reasonably frequently. Read up on [Waking Shark](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2013/nov/12/operation-waking-shark-ii-tests-cybersecurity-banks) 1 and 2 for some of the UK's simulations and for the information on it that has been made public.

It would not make sense to publish detail of mitigation or remediation strategies here, as a savvy attacker would then build them into their attack plan.